# What to use pthread_join,pthread_exit or pthread_cancel while thread in sleep and need to close gracefully?

Tags: c, linux, pthreads, sleep

I have a thread running in while with condition and it has sleep of 2 minutes.
(i.e.

```
while (condition) {
      //do something
      sleep(120);
   }
```

)

To terminate the thread gracefully, I used `pthread_join()` and made **while condition to false** (e.g. `someflag = 0`)

And its working to terminate the thread, but if the thread is sleeping, it doesn't terminate until it finishes sleeping.

This is the problem I need avoid; I need to make thread come out early even if it is in sleep.

Comment: If available send the thread a signal. What platform are you on?

Comment: If your graceful shutdown fits into `pthread_cleanup_push()/pthread_cleanup_pop()`, you can terminate your thread with `pthread_cancel()`, provided cancelability is enabled and asynchronous.

Answer (score 5):

None of the above. Instead of `while (condition) sleep(120);` you should be using a condition variable:

```
while (condition) {
    ...
    pthread_cond_timedwait(&condvar, &mutex, &abstime);
    ...
}
```

I chose `pthread_cond_timedwait` assuming you actually need to wake up and do something every 120 seconds even if nobody signals you, but if not you could just use `pthread_cond_wait` instead. The signaling thread needs to call `pthread_cond_signal(&condvar)` after changing the `condition`, and of course all access (reads and writes) to the state the `condition` depends on need to be protected by a mutex, `mutex`. You have to hold the mutex while calling `pthread_cond_[timed]wait`. If you have further questions on how to use condition variables, search the existing questions/answers (there are lots) or ask a follow-up.

Comment: You write: "_after changing the `condition`, and of course all access (reads and writes) to the state the `condition` depends on need to be protected by a mutex, `mutex`_". Do you mean the loop's `condition` or the thread's `condvar`?

Comment: I mean the loop's condition. If it changes based on things other threads do, all accesses must be controlled by a mutex.

Answer (score 2):

This may not be the right answer, however I can suggest a work around to break `sleep()` of 120 sec into smaller time such as 2 seconds and put that in loop. Every time the loop executes, you can check for condition e.g.

```
while (condition)
{
  //do something

  int i = 0;
  while(condition && (60 > i))
  {
    sleep (2);
    i++;
  }
}
```

I hope someone will surely paste better answer.